# Spider is working perfectly but doesn't scrape some results

Tags: scrapy, web-crawler

It's working fine, there are approx 208 product information, but for some product details, it give no results, I've executed those products link separately in scrapy shell, working fine there, but why it misses out 25% off product details?

I've tried rotating user-agents, applied different xpaths, but in vain.

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from ..items import AmazonItem
import time
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
import urllib.parse


class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'pet'
    start_urls = ['https://www.amazon.co.uk/s?k=moleskine&rh=p_89%3AMoleskine&dc&qid=1567115653&rnid=1632651031&ref=sr_nr_p_89_1',
                  'https://www.amazon.co.uk/s?k=moleskine&rh=p_89%3AMoleskine&dc&page=2',
                  'https://www.amazon.co.uk/s?k=moleskine&rh=p_89%3AMoleskine&dc&page=3',
                  'https://www.amazon.co.uk/s?k=moleskine&rh=p_89%3AMoleskine&dc&page=4',
                  'https://www.amazon.co.uk/s?k=moleskine&rh=p_89%3AMoleskine&dc&page=5'
                  ]

def parse(self, response):
    links =response.xpath("//h2/a[contains(@href,'/dp')]/@href").extract()
    urll = ['https://www.amazon.co.uk' + link for link in links]
    urls = urll
    for url in urls:
        yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse_details)
def parse_details(self, response):
    global name1
    global sales_rank11
    global price1
    global prime1
    list = AmazonItem()
    name = response.xpath(".//*[(@id ='productTitle')]/text()").extract_first()
    if name is None:
        name1 = name
        self.logger.info('skip')
    else:
        name1 = name.replace('\n', '').strip()

    price = response.xpath("//span[@id='price_inside_buybox']/text()").get()
    if price is None:
        price1 = response.xpath("//span[@class='a-color-price']/text()").get()
        if price1 is None:
            price1 = 'No Price Avaiable'
        self.logger.info('skip')
    else:
        price1 = price.replace('\n', '').replace(' ','')

    prime = response.xpath("//span[@id='price-shipping-message']/b").get()
    if prime is None:
        prime1 = 'Not Prime'
    else:
        prime1 = 'Prime'
    sales_rank1 = response.xpath("//tr[@id='SalesRank']/td[@class='value']/text()").get()
    if sales_rank1 is None:
        sales_rank11 = 'No Sales Rank Available'
    else:
        sales_rank11 = sales_rank1.replace('(','').replace('\n','')
    list['Name'] = name1
    list['Price'] = price1
    list['SalesRank'] = sales_rank11
    list['Prime'] = prime1
    list['Url'] = response.url
    yield list
```

[Box 2 conatins correct information, but box 1 doesn't have data, but if we go to the link, there's data there](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZJcII.jpg)
[That's the product name of box 1's url, woking fine in scrapy, but not in spider.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kFwxD.jpg)

Is there something am i missing?

Comment: Can you check the indentation of the code you've posted and post your `AmazonItem` code? It would be good to remove any unnecessary parts of your example too

Comment: Check the responses you get, Amazon my be returning incomplete responses due to you being detected as a bot.

Comment: Thanks for reply, I figured it out, it was giving me captcha response for some pages, any method to prevent that?